# Set parent as overflow hidden to cut off animation but keep showing child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two menus between which you can toggle using a switch. Every menu item has a dropdown that shows when you click on a menu item.

The problem is when clicking the switch, an animation is shown for the transition between the two menus (slide in and slide out). I want to keep the sliding animation only inside the menu element, so I used `overflow-y: hidden;` to make this happen. However this also cuts off my dropdown menus since they are a child of the parent that has `overflow: hidden`.

I made a codepen showing the problem here:

https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/jOMMoom

When you switch the menu, you can see the animation overflows the menu container.

If I use below code the animation looks nice, but the menu doesn't open anymore when clicking on an item.

```
.categoriemenu .categorielijst {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

How can I fix this?

I tried setting the `product-menu` (which is the class of the dropdown menus) to `position:fixed` but this breaks the styling, my menu also has variable heights so I would like to know if there is an easier solution to this?

Comment: There are solutions/workarounds for [“Popping Out of Hidden Overflow”](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/), but those are rather complex, and depend on specific circumstances. I’m guessing your best bet here is to apply `overflow-y: hidden` only for the duration of your menu switch animation, and reset it to the default after.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't think about that. Sounds like a great solution. I will try that.

Comment: @CBroe Got it to work by setting `overflow-y:hidden` only for the duration of the animation. Thank you

Comment: maybe you want to consider writing a self answer with your solution to avoid having the answer only in comments. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting a timer on the `overflow-hidden` for the duration of the animation like this:

```
$('.toggle-switch input').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[name=switch]:checked', '.toggle-switch').val() == 1) {
        $(".categorielijst").css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        $("#menu1").addClass('animate__slideInUp');
        $("#menu2").addClass('animate__slideOutUp');
        $("#menu1").css('display', 'flex');
        $("#menu1").removeClass('animate__slideOutDown');
        $("#menu2").removeClass('animate__slideInDown');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".categorielijst").css('overflow-y', 'visible');
        }, 600)
    } else if ($('input[name=switch]:checked', '.toggle-switch').val() == 2) {
        $(".categorielijst").css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        $("#menu1").css('position', 'absolute')
        $("#menu1").addClass('animate__slideOutDown');
        $("#menu2").addClass('animate__slideInDown');
        $("#menu2").css('display', 'flex');
        $("#menu1").removeClass('animate__slideInDown');
        $("#menu2").removeClass('animate__slideOutUp');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".categorielijst").css('overflow-y', 'visible');
        }, 600);
    }
});
```

It's not perfect because if you spam click the toggle it will still sometimes kind of glitch and overflow out of the container but if you click like a normal person it works fine.